# Before LaTeX editors were invented, how did plain TeX authors output their code?

Tags: typography, plain-tex, printing, output, tex-history

"Output" doesn't just mean PDF files. It could also mean PostScript or plain paper (made from trees).

This might seem like a goofy question, but [I couldn't](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=lm&q=plain+tex+output+before+latex+editors+were+invented&ia=web) find the answer with a search engine. The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX) for TeX has been less than helpful. It explains the developmental history of TeX, but it doesn't name the app(s) that people used to turn plain TeX into output.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.  Do you mean how people used to run TeX without the editor, or how did they look at the output?

Comment: people used the same program as now, tex turns a tex document into dvi then a dvi driver such as dvips turns dvi into postscript. An editor is not really involved at all, other than writing the source file.

Comment: @Phelype Oleinik : How did they look at and produce the output?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109758/how-was-tex-output-visualised-on-screen-back-in-the-day

Comment: there were full screen dvi viewers from the very earliest days, so the process was not that different to now

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : Yup, that answers it. I gave you an upvote on every response. Thanks.